# Writing an Eq instance

Tags: haskell, instance

I have this function:

```
func:: [[[Char]]] -> Int -> [(Int,Int,[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char])] -> [[[Char]]] 
func mymap scope klkl =
```

The function works fine on GHCi but when I run this code on Hugs I get this error :

```
Hugs> :l asdf
ERROR "asdf.hs":238 - Instance of Eq (Int,Int,[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) required for definition of func
```

Can you tell me how I can fix this problem for Hugs? I already have a `show` function for 10-tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your typical `Eq` instance is as braindead as they come. I'll give an example for triples which you can expand with your favorite editor into one for 10-tuples.

```
instance (Eq a, Eq b, Eq c) => Eq (a, b, c) where
    (a, b, c) == (a', b', c') = a == a' && b == b' && c == c'
```